How to mock promisified child process exec with Jest
I'm trying to write a test for this piece of code:
const util = require('node:util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec)

class Command {
  async execute(command) {
    try {
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(command)
      return { code: 0, stdout, stderr }
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        code: error.code,
        stdout: error.stdout,
        stderr: error.stderr
      }
    }
  }
}

I've looked at How to mock a promisified and bound function? and How do I use Jest to mock a promisified function? but I cannot figure out how exactly mock exec or whether I should mock promisify.
I tried this one:
const { Command } = require('../src/utils')

jest.mock('node:child_process', () => ({
  exec: jest.fn()
}))

describe('Command', () => {
  it('executes a command', async () => {
    const command = new Command()
    const cmd = 'la -la'
    const expected = {
      code: 0,
      stdout: cmd,
      stderr: ''
    }

    require('node:child_process').exec.mockReturnValueOnce({
      stdout: cmd,
      stderr: ''
    })

    const result = await command.execute(cmd)
    expected(result).toEqual(expected)
  })
})

but I get thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test..
What should I mock, and how?

Test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing. So if you're mocking exec, especially in the context that you're using it with promisify, you need to make sure it still calls back the callback. Your mock return value is not what the actual implementation does. You could also consider inverting the dependency, so Command receives a function (defaulting to exec) that accepts a command and returns a promise representing its result.

This question is similar to: How to mock a promisified and bound function?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The accepted answer shows a test double that correctly invokes the callback, it's unclear how you've tried to apply that to your case.

Updated my question with problems I had and how I made it work finally. Thanks for suggestions. I think my question was not very similar to the question you suggested. It helped a bit but then I struggled with some exec related things which were not covered by that answer.
